# Daily sales analysis software with charts for very small coffeee shop

Tags: data-analysis

can anyone help me please?
I run a very small coffee shop. I am after a free or cheap piece of software that will allow me to input my daily takings, and then allow me to compare day vs day, week vs week, weather a Monday is better than a tuesday etc.The ability to look at it in chart format is required. I do have MS office but not sure what I would use. It needs to be numpty proof ;-)
Any one have any suggestions please
regards
Woody

Comment: Excel, but you'd have to learn a little about formulas, but it wouldn't be that complex.

Answer (score 0):

## Spreadsheet

Nearly any spreadsheet will let you enter sales by date, calculate the day of the week for each date, perform analysis, and make charts.

For example:

- LibreOffice
- Microsoft Excel
- Apple Numbers.

Invest some time in learning the basics of writing formulas and macros. There will be a learning curve, but you may enjoy the process. Read the manual, google for the samples, and ask around for a spreadsheet jockey to help guide you.